# SVG tag mousedown event with D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, event-handling, dom-events

I have an `<svg></svg>` node and I tried to add `mousedown` event which for some reason doesn't get fired at all, while `click` is working fine, is this behaviour intended and svg tags can't have `mousedown` event attached or I am doing something wrong?

I'm attaching events with d3.js library:

```
 d3.select(svg)
    .on("mousedown", (event) => setRectPoint(event, gContainer))
    .on("mousemove", (event) => drawRectOutline(event, gContainer));
```

Comment: Do you bind any D3 events to your SVG? Do you use D3 V6?

Comment: yes im using d3 v6, i dont bind any other events besides metioned it the post

Comment: Replace `(event) => setRectPoint(event, gContainer)` with `event => console.log(event)`... Do you see anything in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `svg` is already a selection, you don't need to do `d3.select` again.

Below you can see `mousedown` fires when the mouse button is pressed and `click` fires when the button is released.

```js
const svg = d3.select("#viz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 240)
  .attr("height", 180);

const drawRect = (e) => {
  d3.select(e.target)
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", e.x)
    .attr("y", e.y)
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 20);
}

const drawCircle = (e) => {
  d3.select(e.target)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", e.x)
    .attr("cy", e.y)
    .attr("r", 20);
}

svg
  .on("mousedown", e => drawRect(e))
  .on("click", e => drawCircle(e));
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

rect {
  fill: #f00;
}

circle {
  fill: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: in my case it didn't work out because of the strange interaction of react and d3.js(sry forgot to mention it), so if you dont take that into consideration this is the right way to do it